# Close functions have close points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, metric-spaces

Suposse that $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are $C^1$ and

$$\int_0^1{|f-g|^2+|f'-g'|^2~dx}<\varepsilon$$

I would like to know if it is possible to say something about the distance between $f(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)$ for $x_0 \in [0,1]$. In fact, I would like to arrive at if the functions are close, in the sense mentioned above, their points will be too, i.e., $|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|<\delta$, for some small $\delta$, probably depending on $\varepsilon$.

This seems to be a fact mentioned in a proof I'm studying, but I seem to be able to think of counterexamples in my head. I thought of two functions that are the same except in a small region, where I make it as far apart as I want, just control the range where they are different, so the integral above is still true. That was an intuitive thought, actually to think about it I ignored the term that involves the derivative, maybe that's my problem.

I couldn't come to the conclusion that the images of the functions will be close, does anyone have any hint?

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags. How is this differential geometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $h=f-g$ we have
$$|h(x)-h(0)|\le \int\limits_0^x|h'(t)|\,dt \le \int\limits_0^1|h'(t)|\,dt\le
\left (\int\limits_0^1|h'(t)|^2\,dt\right )^{1/2}=\| h'\|_2$$
Thus for $a(x)=h(x)-h(0)$ we obtain
$$\|a\|_2\le \|h'\|_2$$
By the triangle inequality for $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm we get
$$ |h(0)|=\|h-a\|_2\le \|h\|_2+\|a\|_2\le \|h\|_2+\|h'\|_2\le \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\|h\|_2^2+\|h'\|_2^2}$$
Thus $|f(0)-g(0)|\le \sqrt{2\varepsilon}.$

Comment: It seems to me, that I can change the point $0$ by any other point in the $[0,1]$, right?

Comment: Right. Just use $a(x)=h(x)-h(x_0).$